# Best way to format a food menu

Tags: html, css

I'm designing a website for a local restaurant, and I'd like to create their food menus as regular html pages.  The format would look something like this:

Steak..................$15

Fish....................$17

Chicken..............$12

The periods are there to indicate space.  The dishes would be left justified, and the prices right justified.

In the dark ages of barbarianism, the method would be to use tables, and align="right" the second td of each row.  (At least that's what people tell me.  I would never have done something so crude!)

Using divs, the only thing I can come up with is very cumbersome:

```
<div style="float: left">Steak</div>
<div style="float: right;text-align: right">$15</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Or, with *some* improvement:

```
<div>Steak
<div style="float: right;text-align: right">$15</div>
</div>
```

Certainly I'd put the styles into a stylesheet and use classes, but you get the point.

Is there a simpler way to do this?  It just seems like an awful lot of divs.
Thanks for any help

Comment: what do you want to do??/

Comment: You should check out [Codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), be sure to read their FAQ though!

Comment: Tables for templating = bad. For content(like this), I wouldn't think too long about it. Also, the dollar sign should probably be in a separate column(whether you use tables or not) to keep them all vertically aligned. Or a monospace font for the numbers but those are mostly ugly.

Answer (score 1):

### this is how you want

```css
.left{float: left;margin-left:50px}
.right{float: right;margin-right:150px}
```

```html
        <div class="menu">
            <span class="left">Steak</span><span class="right">$15</span><br>
            <span class="left">Fish</span><span class="right">$17</span><br>
            <span class="left">Chicken</span><span class="right">$12</span><br>
```